# JavaScript strings

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to construct a string param to send as a param to an AJAX call, but the various ways I've tried to build the string haven't worked, including simple concatenation. Any suggestions on to do this?

```
var partRelationType = checkBox.name;
var partNumber = checkBox.value;
var isChecked = checkBox.checked;

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SetSelectedPart", "Select", new { customerEstimateKey = ViewBag.CustomerEstimateKey, type = partRelationType, partNumber =  partNumber, isSelected = isChecked })',
    type: "POST",
    async: true
});
```

Comment: WTH is an "@Url.Action"?

Comment: Where's the concentatenation, most of those values looks like they are variables of different sorts, and they need to be added like `url: 'somewebadress'+some_variabel+'morestringadress'+a.different.variable,`

Comment: The url tag of the Ajax function is supposed to call another page on your server. If you want to pass parameters into the page you do so like this: `url:targetPage.html?myParameter=myValue`.

Comment: @BrendanBetts - so a querystring is the way to go for POST requests now ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is created using server side code, so you can't use client side variables as they don't exist yet.

Use the data property for the data instead. I'm not sure how the data is put in the URL by your server code, but something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("SetSelectedPart", "Select", new { customerEstimateKey = ViewBag.CustomerEstimateKey })',
  data: { type: partRelationType, partNumber: partNumber, isSelected: isChecked },
  type: "POST",
  async: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A URL needs to be a URL like `http://www.blah.com.au/foo.aspx?type=bar&id=22` or `just foo.aspx?type=bar&id=22`

Are you missing server side tags around your URL.action?

Or will some template parsing automagically convert into a URL of the format above that it needs to be?

Comment: There is a server tag. The razor syntax uses just a @ to start the server code block, and no end tag.